# How to insert value html from database into javascript with php for CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I want to make edit topic , and for this i need to select data from database ( this data is insert from ckeditor with html tag) I have already done the data selection and storage function in this mode:

```
$getContentTopic = $this->getForumFunctions()->getContentTopic($_GET['tid']);
```

And the javascript code for ckeditor and replace the value i have like that:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'comment' );
    CKEDITOR.instances['comment'].setData('<?php echo $getContentTopic; ?>');

</script>
```

If the value of $getContentTopic is just text , it worked , displayed the text value inside of ckeditor .. but if is html tag i have this error:

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

For exemple my `$getContentTopic` have this value 

Bla bla

 doesn't work, but if have value **Test**  it works.

Comment: you need to set value in textarea and reload ckeditor, thats it

Comment: @Jain if i put just value="<?php echo $getContentTopic; ?>" in textarea doesn't display anything..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolve this.. just add inside of tag `<textarea></textarea>` date from database .. for my form I added so

```
<textarea name="comment" ><?php echo $getContentTopic; ?></textarea>
```